# Welch's ANOVA in Python

Tags: python, scipy

I'm not sure if stackoverflow is the best forum for this, but anyway...

Scipy implements ANOVA using `stats.f_oneway`, which assumes equal variances. It says in the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.f_oneway.html#scipy.stats.f_oneway) that if the variances are unequal, one could consider the Kruskal-Wallis test instead.

However, what I want is Welch's ANOVA. Scipy has a Welch t-test, but of course this doesn't work if I have more than two groups.

What I find interesting is that scipy used to have `stats.oneway` which allowed for an equal variance setting. However, it has been [deprecated](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.oneway.html#scipy.stats.oneway).

Is there an easy way to implement Welch's ANOVA in Python?

Answer (score 3):

Just required the same thing. I had to copy code from R package. Also requested scipy.stats to add this feature. Here is the ~10 lines of code for the implementation

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/11122

Comment: Thanks for creating the issue on scipy. I hope the devs include this in the next release.

Answer (score 2):

The [pingouin](https://pingouin-stats.org/index.html) package has a Welch's ANOVA implemented. You can find the documentation for it at https://pingouin-stats.org/generated/pingouin.welch_anova.html.